# MySQL - Get daily counts for unique keys

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL DB where I store door access... I'm struggling to figure out how to get daily instance counts for each key...

Sample Data:

```
 id  |       timestamp      |  key 
-----------------------------------
  0  |  2013-06-09 14:58:07 |  001
  1  |  2013-06-11 07:21:13 |  001
  2  |  2013-06-11 10:05:11 |  001
  3  |  2013-06-12 07:13:59 |  002
  4  |  2013-06-12 10:05:01 |  002
  5  |  2013-06-12 14:31:01 |  001
  6  |  2013-06-13 11:28:14 |  001
  7  |  2013-06-13 07:00:28 |  002
  8  |  2013-06-14 14:05:13 |  002
  9  |  2013-06-15 09:38:23 |  002
```

What I am hoping to end up with is:

```
key | 09 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | ACCESSED DAYS |
---------------------------------------|---------------- 
001 |  1 |  0 |  2 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |             6 |
002 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  2 |  1 |  0 |  0 |             2 |
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what do your columns represent in the sample? Are they dates?

Comment: I suggest you return a simple ordered array and handle the presentation in the 'presentation layer'/application level code (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Comment: This doesn't look like something MySQL can do on its own (easily).

Comment: Look into the `DAY()` function, you can use this in conjunction with `CASE` statements.  Show what you've tried and people will be more willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select `key`,
       sum(day(timestamp = 9)) as `09`,
       sum(day(timestamp = 10)) as `10`,
       sum(day(timestamp = 11)) as `11`,
       sum(day(timestamp = 12)) as `12`,
       sum(day(timestamp = 13)) as `13`,
       sum(day(timestamp = 14)) as `14`,
       sum(day(timestamp = 15)) as `15`,
       count(distinct date(timestamp)) as accessdays
from t
group by `key`;
```

To get the number of days, just count the distinct days.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm; though, I have one more question... for the days shouldn't the sum be a count since I'm trying to find out how many times the key was used?

Comment: @Kate . . . The `sum()` *is* doing a count.  It is adding "1" every time the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

## Here's my thought process

First, lets select all the days for one key

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(timestamp) FROM sample_data WHERE key = ?
```

Second, let's count the number of columns from the previous result

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as access_days FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DAY(timestamp) from sample_data WHERE key = ?) a
```

Lastly, let's mix it with a `GROUP BY` to get the results from each individual key

```
SELECT
    b.key as key,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DAY(timestamp)
     FROM sample_data a WHERE a.key = b.key)) access_days
FROM sample_data b
GROUP BY b.key
```